# Add fields Automatically If present in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Writing a spider to scrape a website, But got stuck at a problem.
A block of code like below is there. And i want to write a spider that crawls for all the `<li>` tags present inside the `<ul>` tag to extract there `href` Attribute and store it in an incremental variable Such as `Field1` , `Field2` , `Field3` etc With 'Field' being constant and the numerical value increasing  for as many `<li>` tags present

Example Html: (Not putting the original html as it's long)

```
<ul class="l-itemcassette l-space_medium">

    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Having trouble with xpath so using css selectors.

Comment: Euh... I don't see any selectors (or scrapy code)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) over the `response.css()` or `response.xpath()` to index the matching href attribute values:

```
In [1]: {'Field%d' % index: link 
         for index, link in enumerate(response.css("ul.l-itemcassette.l-space_medium li a::attr('href')").extract(), start=1)}
Out[1]: 
{'Field1': u'#link1',
 'Field2': u'#link2',
 'Field3': u'#link3',
 'Field4': u'#link4'}
```

Note that I've assigned different `href` values for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Oh crap, where was this question months ago? This is much cleaner than having a variable incrementing in a `for` cycle. Thanks!